# SSIS 2008 R2: ROUND the float column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl

Table:

```
create table float_dt_test
(
    cola float,
    colb float
);
```

Insertion:

```
insert into float_dt_test values(57,999.857894736842);
insert into float_dt_test values(0.225,999.99);
```

I want to export given data into `.txt` file using SSIS.

I want to export the values round of 6.

Expected Output in txt file:

```
Cola                    Colb
-------------------------------------------
57                      999.857895
0.225                   999.99
```

For which i have written following query:

```
SELECT ROUND(Cola,6) as cola,
       ROUND(Colb,6) as colb 
FROM float_dt_test;
```

But after getting exported file looks like:

```
Cola                    Colb
-------------------------------------------
57                      999.85789499999998
0.22500000000000001     999.99000000000001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rounding the values does not change the internal representation.

After rounding, convert to a decimal:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 6), ROUND(Cola, 6)) as cola,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 6), ROUND(Colb, 6)) as colb 
FROM float_dt_test;
```

Actually, the `ROUND()` is now redundant.  Leaving it in causes no harm because it makes the operations explicit.

Answer (score 1):

In the `DataFlow Task` You can add two `derived columns` from SSIS toolbox with the following expressions:

```
(DT_NUMERIC,10,6)ROUND([Cola],6)

(DT_NUMERIC,10,6)ROUND([Colb],6)
```

And map the two derived columns to the flat file destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly in SSIS by using a Data Conversion Transformation:
[image]

Comment: It is not good idea. Because he needs to round the data also.

Comment: good point, he may need to do the rounding with a Derived Column transformation prior to the data conversion